# Solving Poisson Equation Finite-difference using maple

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, maple

How do I solving Poisson Equation Finite-difference using maple

consider Poisson equation

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}  (x,y)+ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} (x,y) = x*e^y$$

$0<x<2$ , $0<y<1$.

with the boundary conditions

$u(0,y)=0$,  $u(2,y)=2*e^y$ ,  $0\leq y \leq1$.

$u(x,0)=x$,  $u(x,1)=e*x$  ,  $0\leq x \leq 2$

Comment: You can use this finite differencing toolkit for maple: [http://laplace.phas.ubc.ca/People/arman/FD_doc/](http://laplace.phas.ubc.ca/People/arman/FD_doc/)

Answer (score 0):

Elliptic equations are not currently handled by Maple's numeric PDE solvers. You would have to code the linear algebra yourself.